# Get Javascript session in PHP (Symfony)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get a session variable value set in JS with PHP in back-end (I'm using Symfony).

I set my variable like so:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('test-name', file);
```

This works well because I can see in the browser console my session variable and its value. However, on the back-end, I'm unable to get it.
I tried the following:

```
$this->get('session')->get('test-name');
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sessionStorage` is an browser api and does not interact with server sessions.
PHP Sessions are stored on the server side and the client can only reference it with PHPSESSID cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript program and your PHP program are different programs running on (most of the time) different computers.

JavaScript's sessionStorage accesses a store **inside the browser**.

PHP's sessions access a store **on the server**.

They are not the same store.

---

If you want to store the data in a shared location, use the PHP session store. Allow JavaScript access to it by writing a web service and using Ajax to interact with it.